# Why is my gridview populating the incorrect data in my rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I am building a bookstore using GridViews and data from my database. There are checkboxes and each row has a quantity textbox. I am validating to make sure the at least one checkbox is checked and that the selected row has a quantity input before hitting submit. When the user hits submit, the data selected should be populated into another gridview.

The issue i am having is that when i select two different books and hit submit, the books populated on the gridview is just repeating only one book twice.

*Also the lblError text is still showing when i set the visibility to false when I submit.

Here's a snippet of the submit button call:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double saleCount = 0;

    Processor p = new Processor();
    Book objBook = new Book();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBooks.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("cbBook");
        string title = row.Cells[1].Text;
        string authors = row.Cells[2].Text;
        string isbn = row.Cells[3].Text;
        DropDownList gvType = (DropDownList)row.Cells[4].FindControl("ddBookType");
        DropDownList gvMethod = (DropDownList)row.Cells[5].FindControl("ddMethod");
        TextBox qty = (TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("txtQty");

        String strType = Convert.ToString(gvType.Text);
        String strMethod = Convert.ToString(gvMethod.Text);

        if (chkbx.Checked && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(qty.Text)))
        {
            panelHeader.Visible = false;
            panelStudentInfo.Visible = false;
            panelCampus.Visible = false;
            panelCatalog.Visible = false;
            panelStudentInfo2.Visible = true;
            panelCampus2.Visible = true;
            panelCatalog2.Visible = true;
            gvBooks.Visible = false;
            gvOrder.Visible = true;
            panelButtons.Visible = false;

            txtStudentID2.Text = txtStudentID.Text;
            txtStudentName2.Text = txtStudentName.Text;
            txtStudentAddr2.Text = txtStudentAddr.Text;
            txtPhoneNo2.Text = txtPhoneNo.Text;
            ddCampus2.Text = ddCampuses.Text;

            lblError.Visible = false;

            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text);
            objBook.Title = title;
            objBook.Authors = authors;
            objBook.ISBN = isbn;
            objBook.BookType = strType;
            objBook.Method = strMethod;
            objBook.Quantity = quantity;

            objBook.Price = p.Calculate(isbn, strType, strMethod);
            objBook.TotalCost = objBook.Price * objBook.Quantity;
            orderList.Add(objBook);

            saleCount += objBook.Quantity;

            orderTotal = objBook.TotalCost + orderTotal;

            p.UpdateDB(isbn, quantity, strMethod, objBook.TotalCost);
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "* Please select a book & enter a quantity";
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }

        gvOrder.DataSource = orderList;
        gvOrder.DataBind();

        gvOrder.Columns[0].FooterText = "Totals";
        gvOrder.Columns[5].FooterText = saleCount.ToString();
        gvOrder.Columns[6].FooterText = orderTotal.ToString("C2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the declaration and initialization of your Book inside the foreach loop

Comment: @Steve my god thank you so much, but now the error label is still showing when I already made the visibility set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code from this

```
Book objBook = new Book();
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBooks.Rows)
{
    ....
```

to this

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBooks.Rows)
{
    Book objBook = new Book();
    .....
```

The reason is simple. If you create the Book instance outside the loop and, inside the loop, you set its properties and add it to the list, at the second loop you will change the properties of the same instance to different values and add the reference a second time to the list. At the end of the loop your list will have many references to the SAME instance and this single instance will have its properties set to the last values read inside the loop.

If you declare and initialize the Book instance inside the loop you have, at every loop, a different instance of Book to add to the list and each instance will have its own property values.

Looking better at your code, I think that all the code after the if check should go outside the loop even the setting of the datasource.
Here a stripped down layout of the code to highlight the relevant points.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double saleCount = 0;

    Processor p = new Processor();

    // Prepare a list of errors 
    List<string> errors = new List<strig>();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvBooks.Rows)
    {
        Book objBook = new Book();
        ....    
        if (chkbx.Checked)
        {

           // Probably it is better to check here also the quantity value
           // not just for text in the textbox (it could be anything)

           if(Int32.TryParse(qty.Text, out int quantity) && quantity > 0)
           {
                // We have at least one checkbox checked with a quantity, so no error!
               .....
           }
           else
           {
              // We don't have a quantity, add book title to error list....
              errors.Add($"Book {title} has no quantity!");
           }
        }
    }

    // Handle the errors, if any
    if(errors.Count > 0)
    {
        lblError.Text = string.Join("<br/>, errors);
        lblError.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Visible = false;
        gvOrder.DataSource = orderList;
        gvOrder.DataBind();

        gvOrder.Columns[0].FooterText = "Totals";
        gvOrder.Columns[5].FooterText = saleCount.ToString();
        gvOrder.Columns[6].FooterText = orderTotal.ToString("C2");
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked but the error label is still showing when I already made the visibility set to false.

Comment: That should go outside the loop otherwise it will be visible or invisible depending on the checked state of the last checkbox examined in the loop

Comment: that just makes all the validation errors not show up at all.

Comment: If you want to show a validation error, I would add any error message to a `List<string>` and display all the messages in the lblError when you have finieshed to loop over the checked rows

Comment: now i get an error "input string was not in a correct format." @ Line 60:                 int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text);